# Grocery CRUD Operator Dropdown like PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I am working with **Grocery CRUD** Which is very good, but stuck at this point, that how can i add operator dropdown (like PHPMyAdmin) in footer of Grocery CRUD just before the Search Button.

**PHPMyAdmin Operator Dropdown:**

[image]

**Grocery CRUD Footer:**

[image]

Any suggestion will be helpful